# Subtract pairs of images from two image collections to create a collection of difference images, GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, for-loop

I have made two image collections, for pre- and post-event, that correspond to a feature collection of points representing event locations each with a date. I want to subtract each of the pre-event images from the post-event images.

I have tried it with a for loop - but my 'difference' is coming back as undefined, but I can't see what the problem is.

```
// Create difference image for each pair of pre and post event images 
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var pre_image = List_pre[i];
    var post_image = List_post[i];
    var difference = post_image.subtract(pre_image);
  }

  print('difference', difference);
```

For visualisation purposes, I could do what I wanted by mosaicing the images in the image collection, then subtracting. But I want to end up with 3 final image collections of pre, post and difference images.

The full code is here:

```
    var fc_points = ee.FeatureCollection([
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([30.01, 59.80]), {event_date: '2017-06-26', LS_ID: 1}),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([6.4, 50.8012]), {event_date: '2019-08-15', LS_ID: 2}),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([6.11144, 61.4964]), {event_date: '2019-07-30', LS_ID: 3})
    ]);
    var months = 2;
    
    Map.addLayer(fc_points, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'points')
    
    // function create a new feature.
    var getPoints = function(feature) {
      var point = feature.geometry();
      // Return a new Feature, copying properties from the old Feature.
      return ee.Feature(point).copyProperties(feature);
    };
    
    //function create region
    var bufferPoly = function(feature) {
      return feature.buffer(2500).bounds();   // substitute in your value of Z here
    };
    
    //Function to add pre and post dates as a property
    var addDates = function(feature) {
      var event_date = ee.Date(feature.get('event_date'));
        var keepProperties = ['LS_ID'];
        var pre_date = ((event_date).advance((ee.Number(months)).multiply(-1), 'Month'));
      return feature.set({
        post_date : ee.Date((event_date).advance(ee.Number(months), 'Month')),
        pre_date : pre_date,
        event_date : ee.Date((pre_date).advance(ee.Number(months), 'Month'))
      }).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties);
    };
    
    // Map the point getting, date adding and polygon making functions over the features.
    var fc_ROIs = fc_points.map(getPoints).map(addDates).map(bufferPoly);
    var count = fc_points.size();
    print ('count', count);
    
    Map.addLayer(fc_ROIs, {}, 'ROIs');
    print ('ROIs', fc_ROIs);
    
    // function Add NDVI  
      function addS2NDVI(image) {
        var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
        return image.select(['B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2']).addBands(ndvi);
      }
    
    //function: make pre image
    var makePreImage = function(feature) {
      var geometry = feature.geometry();
      var pre_date = ee.Date(feature.get('pre_date'))
      var event_date = ee.Date(feature.get('event_date'));
      var keepProperties = ['LS_ID'];
        var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2") // load and filter image collection, then add NDVI 
          .filterDate(pre_date, event_date)
          .filterBounds(geometry)
        S2 = S2.map(addS2NDVI)
      return S2.qualityMosaic('NDVI').set({'image': 'pre'}).clip(geometry).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties); // returns a greenest-pixel composite image
    }
    
    //function: make post image
    var makePostImage = function(feature) {
      var geometry = feature.geometry();
      var post_date = ee.Date(feature.get('post_date'))
      var event_date = ee.Date(feature.get('event_date'));
      var keepProperties = ['LS_ID'];
      var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")// load and filter image collection, then add NDVI   
          .filterDate(event_date, post_date)
          .filterBounds(geometry)
        S2 = S2.map(addS2NDVI)
      return S2.qualityMosaic('NDVI').set({'image': 'post'}).clip(geometry).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties); // returns a greenest-pixel composite image
    }
    
    //map the image collection making functions over the ROI features 
      var greenest_pre = ee.ImageCollection(fc_ROIs.map(makePreImage));
      var greenest_post = ee.ImageCollection(fc_ROIs.map(makePostImage));
      Map.addLayer(greenest_pre, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'pre');
      Map.addLayer(greenest_post, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'post');

//For Loop option    
    var List_pre = greenest_pre.toList(count);
    var List_post = greenest_post.toList(count);
    
    print('List pre', List_pre);
    print('List_post', List_post);
   
   
    // Create difference image for each pair of pre and post event images 
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        var pre_image = ee.Image(List_pre[i]);
        var post_image = ee.Image(List_post[i]);
        var difference = post_image.subtract(pre_image);
      }
    
      print('difference', difference);

    //Mosaic option 
    var ndvi_params = {bands:'NDVI', min:-0.5, max:0.1};
    
    var pre_mosaic = greenest_pre.mosaic(); 
    var post_mosaic = greenest_post.mosaic(); 
    var diff_mosaic = post_mosaic.subtract(pre_mosaic);
    print(diff_mosaic)
    Map.addLayer(diff_mosaic, ndvi_params, 'diff');
```

Comment: I'm also trying to map a function across the two image collections, in various different firms, but have not been successful with this option so far either (I am quite new to any coding).    
    
` var difference = (greenest_pre, greenest_post).map(function (pre_image, post_image) {
  return pre_image.subtract(post_image)
})  
  
  print (difference)`

Comment: Could you please share the link to the GEE script?

Comment: I have something strange with my account where I have never been able to share things (have you heard of that problem before?). But the long bit of code I included should work on its own if you copy-paste it into the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combine()` function to get all bands in one image. As a result, bands of first image in both collection will be combined together in a new image. After that you can use `map()` function to subtract the bands.

```
var image_comb=greenest_post.combine(greenest_pre)
var diff=image_comb.map(function(img){ 
  var b_8= img.select(0).subtract(img.select(5));
  var b_4=img.select(1).subtract(img.select(6));
  var b_3=img.select(2).subtract(img.select(7));
  var  b_2=img.select(3).subtract(img.select(8));
  var ndvi=img.select(4).subtract(img.select(9));
  return ee.Image([b_8,b_4,b_3,b_2,ndvi])
}); 
var diff_image=diff.mosaic()
```